Martial arts manga in which the female lead wants to learn alchemy so they have to test her element
I'm looking for a martial arts manga. It was full color. It was not romance focused. Presumed to be a Chinese manhua. It was set in a Murim world.
The only thing I can remember is that the main character (MC) is female, reincarnated and overpowered.
The MC, who is going to a martial arts school, wants to learn alchemy so they have to test her element. She and the principal (who likes, not loves her) come along. She stands in the middle of the room with a bunch of different colored rocks around her representing different elements, which all light up. The principal is excited to tell everyone, but she asks him to say she only has the element she needs to study alchemy, saying "a tree that grows too tall will catch more wind in a forest," by which she meant that standing out would not help her, to which he agrees. When she exits, her rival (also female) mocks her and boasts that she has two or three elements and that your MC is nothing special.
I don't know correctly how her relationship with her family is or what her status was (noble/princess). I think her hair was black but am not sure.
micht be a reincarnated as a villainess story ?

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

i think black but am not sure

Do you recall if the story was set in Europe, Asia, or somewhere else? This previous manga you asked about appears to be set in a fantasy version of Europe, for example.

asia
sorry for the confusion but i thought that martial arts would be a clear indication sins most are set in asia
if it wasn't i whould have clarified (but thanks for the advise)

Sounds like this is probably a Chinese manhua then.

is that a comic tipe (manga /manwha)?

Japanese comics are manga, Chinese comics are manhua, and Korean comics are manhwa. We use the 'manga' tag for all three, but those are the specific terms for the comics of each of those nations.
